# How to avoid multiple registering of events

Tags: c#, .net

i have an event where i register event handlers.

```
event Action OnGameList;
```

then for example i reach some code like this:

```
backend.OnGameList += ProcessGameList;
backend.GetGameList(); //this will trigger the above event.
```

every time i reach this code, the handler is ADDED. that means the second time it will be called twice.
of course i could remove it in the function like this:

```
backend.OnGameList -= ProcessGameList;
```

but i have the feeling that there is a better solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: Without more code its hard to say. The obvious answer is to only add the event once in code that you don't call repeatedly but its hard to give more specific advice without understanding why you would be adding it multiple times already.

Comment: You can safely remove first and then add again. Otherwise you would have to check if it is already registered.

Comment: I must admit, if my Design is only used by me and i want to attach handlers only once even if the attaching routine is called n times( lets say, each time a custom popup should show up) i always use -=  prior to +=. It never crashed and always helped. Iirc.

Comment: In wandering around the [Observer Design Pattern Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519622%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and related pages, it appears that Dennis' answer provides the expected semantics: attempts to subscribe a single handler more than once are ignored and the first unsubscribe removes the handler.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use some kind of backing field to track that you are already subscribed. I.e.

```
    private bool _subscribed = false;

    SubscribeToOnGameListEvent();
    backend.GetGameList();

    private void SubscribeToOnGameListEvent()
    {
        if (!_subscribed)
        {
            backend.OnGameList += ProcessGameList;
            _subscribed = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the presence of particular delegate in invocation list:

```
class Foo
{
    private EventHandler bar;

    public event EventHandler Bar
    {
        add
        {
            if (bar == null)
            {
                bar = value;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!bar.GetInvocationList().Contains(value))
                {
                    bar += value;
                }
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public void RaiseBar()
    {
        if (bar != null)
        {
            bar(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that seems like a good solution, however in my specific case i cant really use it, since my events are those auto generated classes from a WCF Service Refernce.